# Oja's rule gives unit eigenvector

Tags: unsupervised-learning, eigenvalues

Does Oja's rule for normalized Hebbian learning always result in a unit eigenvector which corresponds to the largest eigenvalue? Or are there any specific conditions or assumptions under which this is true? Does Oja's rule require explicit normalization of the unit vector, and what would be the effect of doing so, if any?

Answer (score 1):

The paper [a simplified neuron model as a principal component analyzer](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebhiksha/courses/deeplearning/Fall.2016/pdfs/OJA.pca.pdf) answers all questions in detail.

To briefly summarize it, the Oja's rule:
$$
\Delta w = w_{n+1} - w_{n} = \eta y_{n} (x_{n} - y_{n}w_{n})
$$

converges to the eigenvector corresponding to the highest eigenvalue, if $\eta$ decreases proportionally to $1/n$, and the autocorrelation matrix $C=E[x_{n}x^{t}_{n}]$ is definite positive with the highest eigenvalue with multiplicity one.

Please go through the paper, and if you have trouble with some parts, ask again on specific points. The corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oja%27s_rule) is also quite helpful.

Comment: I think the update rule is $\eta y_n (x_n - y_n w_n)$, but my specific question was about whether this rule is guaranteed to converge, or can there be any cases where the update term grows indefinitely due to $y_n$? Shouldn't $y_n\geq 0$?